# Why am i getting this error about overload calls?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Good afternoon, i'm receiving this error when using createStore, could someone please explain me what i'm doing wrong?

```
TypeScript error in /workspace/weatherAppTypescript/App/appfrontend/src/redux/store/index.ts(7,31):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<CityProps, any>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown> | undefined): Store<CityProps, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: CityProps | undefined, action: any) => { temp: any; feelslike: any; cityname: any; weatherdesc: any; } | { cityname: any; temp?: undefined; feelslike?: undefined; weatherdesc?: undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<CityProps, any>'.
      Type '{ temp: any; feelslike: any; cityname: any; weatherdesc: any; } | { cityname: any; temp?: undefined; feelslike?: undefined; weatherdesc?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'CityProps'.
        Type '{ cityname: any; temp?: undefined; feelslike?: undefined; weatherdesc?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'CityProps'.
          Types of property 'temp' are incompatible.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<CityProps, any>, preloadedState?: { temp: number; feelslike: number; cityname: string; weatherdesc: string; } | undefined, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, {}> | undefined): Store<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: CityProps | undefined, action: any) => { temp: any; feelslike: any; cityname: any; weatherdesc: any; } | { cityname: any; temp?: undefined; feelslike?: undefined; weatherdesc?: undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<CityProps, any>'.  TS2769

    5 | 
    6 | export default function configureStore() {
  > 7 |     const store = createStore(weatherApp);
      |                               ^
    8 |     return store
    9 | }
```

This is my Store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({weatherApp,});

export default function configureStore() {
    const store = createStore(weatherApp);
    return store
}
```

And this is my reducer:

```
    temp: 0,
    feelslike: 0,
    cityname: "London",
    weatherdesc: ""
}

export function weatherApp(state = initialState, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'changeCity': {
        return {
            temp: action.temp,
            feelslike: action.feelslike,
            cityname: action.cityname,
            weatherdesc: action.weatherdesc
        }
        }
        case 'changeAPI': {
        return {
            cityname: action.cityname
        }
    }
        default:
        return state;
    }
```

And this is the CityProps interface:

```
export interface CityProps {
    temp: number;
    feelslike: number;
    cityname: string;
    weatherdesc: string;
}
```

Thank you so much! i really have no ideas of how to fix this and i'm trying since some hours.... Thank so much for anyone who help me ^^

Answer (score 1):

Because `weatherApp` is function and `createStore` expect the first argument as object.

How ever you have `rootReducer`, pass rootReducer as a first argument. But first, make changes
`const rootReducer = combineReducers({ weatherApp: weatherApp });`

Comment: Thank you so so so so so so so much, really <3 <3 <3

Comment: but now the fnction changeCity returns undefined ;-